# Does not my HP laptop have an internal webcam?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam, hp-elitebook

I have a workstation laptop ( EliteBook 8560w) working on windows 10. I cannot run the webcam with any application I've tried. No webcam is shown on the device manger list, and when I try to install a driver form HP site an error comes out.

Here what I've got for hardware view and the listed built-in devices in BIOS

[image]

[image]

( There is no webcam existing in that list!!)

Comment: Doesn’t look like a webcam to me. Different models of the same series may have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webcam, if fitted, is where the large circle is shown in your pictures. The smaller circle on the left is the camera on light. The small circle on the left is the ambient light sensor.
http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03424153

So your model does not have a webcam.